# How handle with object keys when we type dynamic objects?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have some component that can render data of any object, so I use generic here, but I have some
problems here  
 `{field} : {el[field]}`
What is correct way handle this in my example

https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-thompson-gim2d1?file=/src/App.tsx

I know that we can use something like this `{field} : {el[field as SomeInterface]}` or just
add some record property into interface, but I still have problem(

You can see my code in the link above, and I also leave it here.

```
type WrapperProps<T> = {
  data: T[];
};

function Wrapper<T extends object>({ data }: WrapperProps<T>) {
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((el) => {
        return Object.keys(el).map((field) => {
          return (
            <div key={el + field}>
              {field} : {el[field]}  // type error here
            </div>
          );
        });
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

interface IData {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

interface IData2 {
  email: string;
  passport: string;
}

export default function App() {
  const data1: IData[] = [
    { name: "Alex1", age: 133 },
    { name: "Alex2", age: 33 }
  ];

  const data2: IData2[] = [
    { email: "email", passport: "passport1" },
    { email: "email2", passport: "passport2" }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Wrapper data={data1} />
      <hr />
      <Wrapper data={data2} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the *compilerOptions/lib* in *tsconfig.json* to "es2017", and use `Object.entries()` that will extract the value directly ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-paper-gige0n)):

```
{data.map((el) => {
  return Object.entries(el).map(([field, value]) => {
    return (
      <div key={el + field}>
        {field} : {value}
      </div>
    );
  });
})}
```

**Note**: the expression `el + field` would result in "[object object]" + the text of the field, so the key won't be unique. You should probably use specific value of each object (`id` for example) as a basis for the key. Furthermore, you should also use `Array.flatMap()` to get a single array, and not array of arrays. You can also remove redundant returns, since you're using arrow functions:

```
{data.flatMap(el => Object.entries(el).map(([field, value]) => (
  <div key={`${el.id}-${field}`}>
    {field} : {value}
  </div>
)))}
```

Comment: Thanks, so with Object,keys there ara no good way to handle it?

Comment: As you said, you can cast the field when using it `{el[field as keyof T]}` - https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-hertz-0pmkcw.

Comment: nice, and thanks for key) silly mistake)